# Folder infrastructure for Pentaho Ketlle on Windows Server

Tags: directory, pentaho, kettle

Well I am pretty new on Pentaho Data Integration (Kettle) and I have a lot of questions, but for sure the folder structure is a very important one before to start developing anything, and I have no idea what are the best pratices for that. May Someone help me with some working example and a brief explanation. Basically wWhat I need is how you guy have organized all you transformations and jobs.

I appreciate your time. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will be using CE:

Tools > Repository [ setup a repository here ] once created follow Tools > Repository > Connect

Here all the transformations and jobs will be saved by default, yesterday i had installed 6.1 and they have placed a new option in the repository setup.

1. Pentaho Repository [ NEW, saves in the BISERVER repositories]
2. Kettle Database Repository [ stores somewhere internally ]
3. Kettle File Repository [ stores any location you specify ]

Hope this helps :)